# Add textblock to stackpanel in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, stackpanel

I am using this code to write a Textblock in C# to a Xaml Page

```
 Sale.Name = "Price";
  Sale.Text = "$200";
  deatilLayout.Children.Add(Sale);
  Grid.SetRow(Sale, 1);
```

This just make the text "$200" appear on the page.

How do I place this textblock in a Stackpanel in the row 2 of the grid?

See below for the alyout of the page and where I want the textblock

```
<Grid  x:Name="deatilLayout">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="50 0 0 30" Height="600" Width="1200">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="52" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
       **//Place textblock from C# here**
         </StackPanel>
         </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add it to a `StackPanel` before you add it to the grid.

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(Sale);
deatilLayout.Children.Add(sp);
Grid.SetRow(sp, 2);
```

Comment: Still getting a problem positioning it. Please see the edited code above.

Comment: I don't see anything named `deatilLayout` what are you adding stuff too?

Comment: `detailLayout` is the Name of the Main Grid

Comment: OK so you probably actually want to add it to one of the child panels.  Steve's answer is a good way, give your `StackPanel` a name and add to it as he describes in his answer.

Comment: If you see my comment below, I still get an error. The C# code does not recognize the Name given to the stackpanel

Answer (score 1):

Give your `StackPanel` a name:

```
<StackPanel Name="MyStackPanel">
   ...
</StackPanel>
```

Then in your code, simply add your control to it:

```
Sale.Name = "Price";
Sale.Text = "$200";
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(Sale);
```

This makes the assumption that this code is going in the code-behind of the XAML.

Comment: Yes it is the code behind the Xaml. But when I try this I get this error on `price`: Error `The name "price" does not exist in the current context`

Comment: You wrote `<StackPanel Name="price">` in your xaml?

Comment: In my answer above, nothing is named `price`. There is a control of type `StackPanel` with the name `MyStackPanel`, and a variable in the code behind named `Sale` that holds some kind of control that is being added to the `Children` property of `MyStackPanel`.